# Shortcuts for opening different windows of same program

Tags: window, windows-xp, autohotkey, shortcut

I am using five windows of the same game on Windows XP at the same time and need to switch between them randomly and constantly. I would like to create a keyboard shortcut for every specific window of the game. So I can't just use alt-tab, I need to be able to switch immediately from window one to window three, for example. Is there any way, perhaps using AHK, to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:
F6 to search for all windows with a specific title. F1-F5 to activate them.

```
myWindows := GetWindows("Example window title)
F6::
    myWindows := GetWindows("Example window title")
Return
F1::
    WinActivate, % "AHK_id " myWindows[1]
Return
F2::
    WinActivate, % "AHK_id " myWindows[2]
Return
F3::
    WinActivate, % "AHK_id " myWindows[3]
Return
F4::
    WinActivate, % "AHK_id " myWindows[4]
Return
F5::
    WinActivate, % "AHK_id " myWindows[5]
Return

GetWindows(title) {
    winArray := []
    WinGet, id, list, %title%
    Loop, %id% 
        winArray[A_Index] := id%A_Index%
    Return winArray
}
```

You can find the window title of your game(s) using AutoIt3 Window Spy which comes with AutoHotkey. It's in your AutoHotkey folder and is called AU3_Spy.exe